# Make One query from three query

Tags: jquery, oracle

there is a three query want to make it one note that `hrv_empworkingarea`table is view table

```
   select count(distinct dept_no) 
      total_dept 
   FROM hrv_empworkingarea  
      where short_name LIKE 'IN'  AND active_flag='Y'; 

   select count(a.doctor_no) 
       total_doctor 
   from   hpms_doctor a  
       where   a.active_flag= 'Y';

   select count(job_id) 
      totalNurse 
   from   HR_EMPLOYEE   
      where   job_id= '155';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct dept_no) AS total_dept, (
  SELECT COUNT(a.doctor_no)   
   FROM hpms_doctor a  
   WHERE a.active_flag= 'Y'
) AS total_doctor ,
(
  SELECT COUNT(job_id) 
   FROM HR_EMPLOYEE   
   WHERE job_id= '155'
) AS totalNurse 
   FROM hrv_empworkingarea  
   WHERE short_name LIKE 'IN'  AND active_flag='Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the fact this seems single result (total value without group by)
you can also obtain the result in single row this way

```
select 
      max(total_dept) total_dept
    , max(total_doctor) total_doctor
    , max(totalNurse) totalNurse
from (
   select count(distinct dept_no) total_dept, null  total_doctor, null totalNurse
   FROM hrv_empworkingarea  
      where short_name LIKE 'IN'  AND active_flag='Y'; 
   UNION ALL
   select null, count(a.doctor_no), null 
       total_doctor 
   from   hpms_doctor a  
       where   a.active_flag= 'Y';
   UNION ALL 
   select null, null, count(job_id) 
      totalNurse 
   from   HR_EMPLOYEE   
      where   job_id= '155'
);
```